# PHP Redirect Issues

Tags: php, html, forms

At the moment, I have form in my index.html file:

```
<div id="submit">
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select your file: <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
</div><!--end submit-->
```

It runs the code I have in the upload.php file however, I would like the page to return to the index.html file.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: `<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Using this means that the code in the upload.php file is not executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you're done processing the form in `upload.php`, include the code:

```
header('Location: index.html');
exit;
```

This will only work if `upload.php` isn't actually outputting anything (including whitespace).

Comment: The `Location` header should always (at least for now) contain a full URI.

Comment: Because the spec tells us: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Comment: @PeeHaa learned something today, thanks.